# Why use static_cast for auto pointer in C++11?

Tags: c++11, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I saw that cocos2dx (v3) example :

```
auto target = static_cast<Sprite*>(event->getCurrentTarget());
```

Why not use `dynamic_cast()`? It is not static variable.

Comment: _"It is not static variable"_. `static_cast` is unrelated to a variable being `static`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`static_cast()` has nothing to do with `static` specifier. If performs the cast during **compile time** (i.e. "statically"), which was possible in case of the code you have added to your question.

On the other side, `dynamic_cast()` is performed during **runtime**.

Comment: Note that a `static_cast` can still include a runtime computation (moving the pointer around), but that computation itself is known at compile time, it does not depend on the value of the pointer nor on the object pointed to.

Comment: static_cast just like c language (Class)target method

Comment: @zszen This only holds in the cases where `static_cast` is valid. Where it's not, C-style cast will silently turn into a `reinterpret_cast` (possibly with a `const_cast` added). That's the reason why C-style casts are so dangerous and best avoided in C++.